# Command finished with error code 0: adb -s,emulator-5554,shell,ps

Tags: android, cordova

So, recently I reinstalled Android Studio, and now I'm trying to run my first Apache Cordova application.

This what cmd.exe is telling me after `cordova -d emulate android`:
[image: This what cmd.exe is telling me after cordova -d emulate android]

So I'm kinda lost and don't know where to find an answer.